# Is the diagonal map $\mathbb{C} \to \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{C}$ an etale map of rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is the diagonal map $\mathbb{C} \to \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{C}$ an etale map of rings? Is it of finite type?

Is the map $\operatorname{Spec} \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{C} \to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ an etale map of schemes?

Comment: Does it look like it is of finite type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A\to B$ is a morphism of finite type, then $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra and, in particular, has rank at most countable over $A$.

Your product, on the other hand, has uncountable dimension over the complex numbers.

Comment: nice argument. thanks! and since it is not of finite type, it follows by definition that the map of rings is not etale, since finite type is a requirement for being etale. The map on schemes I think may be etale since etale is local on the base.

Comment: @yogeshmore No, it is not. A morphism of affine schemes is étale if and only if the corresponding ring homomorphism is étale.

Comment: @ZhenLin That's what I thought too, and in fact that's exactly why I asked this question! But the "only if" direction is not true. In my question, the map  on schemes is etale since geometrically it is a disjoint union of infinitely many points mapping to a point. See my confusion here:http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Z0#comment-1447

Comment: No. Your confusion comes from the fact that Spec does not take infinite products to disjoint unions.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, you are right! The infinite disjoint union can't be affine because it isn't quasi-compact.